# BATS: Make variable persistent across all tests

Tags: bash, testing, bats-core

I'm writing a [BATS](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) (Bash Automated Testing System) script and what I'd like is a variable to be persisted across all the tests. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

# Generate random port number
port_num=$(shuf -i 2000-65000 -n 1)

@test "Test number one" {
    a = $port_num
}

@test "Test number two" {
    b = $port_num
}
```

When evaluated, a and b should equal each other. This doesn't work, though, because (according to the docs) the entire file is evaluated after each test run. Which means $port_num gets regenerated between tests. Is there a way/place for me to store variables that will be persisted for across all tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export it as an environmental variable.

```
# If ENV Var $port_num doesn't exist, set it.
if [ -z "$port_num" ]; then
    export port_num=$(shuf -i 2000-65000 -n 1)
fi
```

In `BATS` you must call `load` to source a file.

Put the above code in a file named `port.bash` in the directory you are executing from.

Then before your functions, call `load port`. This will set up your `$port_num` once, and not change it.

```
load port

@test "Test number one" {
    a = $port_num
}

@test "Test number two" {
    b = $port_num
}
```

Comment: Injecting the port number with env variable is fine. But `source` it in current shell (instead of `bats`) may not be what he intended.

Comment: Updated the answer for sourcing in BATS.